# Functions not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, function

keep getting the error that any functions i try to call are not declared in this scope. Here is the code block. The compiler returns the error for any functions that are called that "XXX is not declared in this scope" I wasn't really sure where the problem might be, so I've included all of the code. Sorry there is a lot. And thanks for any help on this you can offer.

Here is a small example of something that is not working properly.

```
void kitchenOption(void);
int main()
{
kitchenOption();
}
/******************************
* Function Name: kitchenOption
* Return Type: none
* Parameters: none
* Description: Gives the Kitchen Options and updates the global variable.
* ****************************/
void kitchenOption(void)
{
    std::cout << "You may add deluxe wooden cabinets and granite cabinets for an additional $20,000." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "If you would like deluxe cabinets and countertops, please input 1." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "If you do not want deluxe cabinets and countertops, please input 2." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> kitchenChoice;

    if(kitchenChoice == 1)
    {
            std::cout << "You have selected deluxe cabinets and contertops. This adds $20,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
            optionalFeaturesCost += 20000;
            std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is now $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
    }
    else if(kitchenChoice == 2)
    {
            std::cout << "You have selected to not have deluxe caibnets and countertops." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
            std::cout << "That is not a valid input." << std::endl;
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

This^ function is an example of something that is not working properly. The rest of the code is below:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::fixed;

#include<iomanip>
using std::setprecision;

#include <stdlib.h>

//Fixed Variable Declarations and Assignments
float STATE_TAX_RATE = .075;
float PERCENT_PROFIT = .25;
float COST_PER_SQUARE_FT = 66.67;

//Variable declarations and Initial Assignments
double houseSquareFootage = 0.0;
double basicHomeCost = 0.0;
double profit = 0.0;
double netHomeCost = 0.0;
double taxes = 0.0;
double totalHomeCost = 0.0;
double optionalFeaturesCost = 0.0;
double discount = 0.0;
int houseChoice = 0;
int bedroomChoice = 0;
int kitchenChoice = 0;
int interiorChoice = 0;
int loopVar = 1;
int loopChoice = 0;

//Function Declarations
int houseOption(void);
void welcomeMessage(void);
void bedroomOption(void)
void kitchenOption(void);
void designOption(void);
void displayDiscount(void);
void displaySummary(void);
void dmoreQuoteOption(void);
void thankYouMessage(void);

int main()
{
do{
//reset Variables
houseChoice = 0;
bedroomChoice = 0;
kitchenChoice = 0;
interiorChoice = 0;
optionalFeaturesCost = 0;
discount = 0;

//Welcome Message
welcomeMessage();

//House Option
houseChoice = houseOption();

if(houseChoice == 1)
{
        std::cout << "You have selected the standard house." << std::endl;
        houseSquareFootage = 3000;
        displaySummary();
        moreQuoteOption();
}
else if (houseChoice == 2)
{

std::cout << "You have selected a custom house." << std::endl;

//Bedroom Option
bedroomOption();

//Kitchen Option
kitchenOption();

//Design Option
designOption();

//Discount
displayDiscount();

//Run Calculations and Report
displaySummary();
}

else
{
        std::cout << "That is not a valid input" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
}
} while (loopVar <= 5);
}

/*************************************
 * Function Type: welcomeMessage
 * Return Type: none
 * parameters: none
 * Description: Welcomes the user to the house pogram
 * **********************************/
void welcomeMessage(void)
{
        std::cout << "Weloome to the House Selection Program." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "This program will allow you to select features for" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " and calculate costs for up to 5 houses." << std::endl;
}

/*************************************
 * Function Name: houseOption
 * Return Type: Int
 * Parameters: none
 * Description: Gives the house options and returns an int to save the info.
 *********************************** /
int houseOption(void)
{
        std::cout << "Would you like a standard house or a custom house?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Input 1 for a standard house or 2 for a custom house." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> houseChoice;
        return houseChoice;
}

/*********************************
 * Function Name: bedroomOption
 * Return Type: none
 * Parameters: none
 * Description: Gives the bedroom options and updates the globabl variable.
 * *****************************/
void bedroomOption(void)
{
        std::cout << "You may add 1 or 2 extra bedrooms. Each bedroom will add 360 sq ft to the house." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter 0 for no extra bedrooms, 1 for one extra bedroom, or 2 for two extra bedrooms." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> bedroomChoice;

        if(bedroomChoice == 0)
        {
                std::cout << "You have chosen to not have any extra bedrooms. The Square Footage of the house is 3000." << std::endl;
                houseSquareFootage = 3000;
                return houseSquareFootage;
        }
        else if(bedroomChoice == 1)
        {
                std::cout << "You have chosen to add one extra bedroom. The Square Footage of the house is 3360." << std::endl;
                houseSquareFootage = 3360;
                return houseSquareFootage;
        }
        else if(bedroomChoice == 2)
        {
                std::cout << "You have chosen to add two extra bedrooms. The Square Footage of the house is 3720." << std::endl;
                houseSquareFootage = 3720;
                return houseSquareFootage;
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "That is not a valid input." << std::endl;
                exit(1);
        }


}

/******************************
 * Function Name: kitchenOption
 * Return Type: none
 * Parameters: none
 * Description: Gives the Kitchen Options and updates the global variable.
 * ****************************/
void kitchenOption(void)
{
        std::cout << "You may add deluxe wooden cabinets and granite cabinets for an additional $20,000." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "If you would like deluxe cabinets and countertops, please input 1." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "If you do not want deluxe cabinets and countertops, please input 2." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> kitchenChoice;

        if(kitchenChoice == 1)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected deluxe cabinets and contertops. This adds $20,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 20000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is now $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(kitchenChoice == 2)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected to not have deluxe caibnets and countertops." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "That is not a valid input." << std::endl;
                exit(1);
        }
}

/***************************
 * Function Name: designOption
 * Return Type: none
 * Parameters: none
 * Description: Gives the Design options and updates the global variable.
 * *************************/
void designOption(void)
{
        std::cout << "There are four interior options and are as follows..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 1: Hardwood floors for the den, kitchen, and family room. Cost: $10,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 2: All of Option 1 as well as solid brass lighting fixtures in and out. Cost: $20,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 3: All of Option 2 as well as plush carpeting, ceramic tile, and real wood paneling. Cost: $25,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 4: All of Option 3 as well as gold kitchen and bath fixtures, Jacuzzi and Sauna. Cost: $30,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please input 0 for no extra interior features, 1 for Option 1, 2 for Option 2, 3 for Option 3, or 4 for Option 4." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> interiorChoice;

        if(interiorChoice == 0)
        {
                std::cout << "You have chosen to not have any extra interior features." << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 1)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 1. This adds $10,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 10000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 2)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 2. This adds $20,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 20000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 3)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 3. This adds $25,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 25000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 4)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 4. This adds $30,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                option  alFeaturesCost += 30000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "That is not a valid input." << std::endl;
                exit(1);
        }
}

/*************************
 * Function Name: displayDiscount
 * Return Type: none
 * Parameters: none
 * Description: Checks for discount and displays it. This function also performs the role of calculateDiscount().
 * ************************/
void displayDiscount(void)
{
        std::cout << "If the optional features cost exceeds $30,000, a 10% discount on the optional features will be awarded." << std::endl;

        if(optionalFeaturesCost >= 30000)
        {
                discount = optionalFeaturesCost*0.1;
                std::cout << "An Optional Features Cost of $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost <<
                " exceeds the requirement of $30,000, and thus a 10% discount of $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << discount
                << " has been awarded." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
                        std::cout << "An Optional Features Cost of $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost <<
                " does not meet the requirement of $30,000, and thus, no discount is awarded." << std::endl;
        }
}

/***********************
 * Function Name: displaySummary
 * Return type: none
 * Parameters: none
 * Description: Displays all relevant info as a summary. This function also performs the role of calculateFinalCost().
 * *******************/
void displaySummary(void)
{
        //Calculating Basic Home Cost
        basicHomeCost = houseSquareFootage * COST_PER_SQUARE_FT;

        //Calculating Profit
        profit = (basicHomeCost + optionalFeaturesCost) * PERCENT_PROFIT;

        //Calculating Net Home Cost
        netHomeCost = basicHomeCost + optionalFeaturesCost + profit - discount;

        //Calculating Taxes
        taxes = netHomeCost * STATE_TAX_RATE;

        //Calculating totalHomeCost
        totalHomeCost = netHomeCost + taxes;

        //Reporting Information
        std::cout << "House Square Footage: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << houseSquareFootage << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Basic Home Cost: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << basicHomeCost << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Optional Features Cost: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Discount: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << discount << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Net Home Cost: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << netHomeCost << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Profit: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << profit << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Taxes: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << taxes << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total Home Cost: " << setprecision(2) << fixed << totalHomeCost << std::endl;
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected deluxe cabinets and contertops. This adds $20,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 20000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is now $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(kitchenChoice == 2)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected to not have deluxe caibnets and countertops." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "That is not a valid input." << std::endl;
                exit(1);
        }
}

/***************************
 * Function Name: designOption
 * Return Type: none
 * Parameters: none
 * Description: Gives the Design options and updates the global variable.
 * *************************/
void designOption(void)
{
        std::cout << "There are four interior options and are as follows..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 1: Hardwood floors for the den, kitchen, and family room. Cost: $10,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 2: All of Option 1 as well as solid brass lighting fixtures in and out. Cost: $20,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 3: All of Option 2 as well as plush carpeting, ceramic tile, and real wood paneling. Cost: $25,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 4: All of Option 3 as well as gold kitchen and bath fixtures, Jacuzzi and Sauna. Cost: $30,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please input 0 for no extra interior features, 1 for Option 1, 2 for Option 2, 3 for Option 3, or 4 for Option 4." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> interiorChoice;

        if(interiorChoice == 0)
        {
                std::cout << "You have chosen to not have any extra interior features." << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 1)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 1. This adds $10,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 10000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 2)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 2. This adds $20,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 20000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 3)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 3. This adds $25,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;

        if(kitchenChoice == 1)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected deluxe cabinets and contertops. This adds $20,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 20000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is now $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(kitchenChoice == 2)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected to not have deluxe caibnets and countertops." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "That is not a valid input." << std::endl;
                exit(1);
        }
}

/***************************
 * Function Name: designOption
 * Return Type: none
 * Parameters: none
 * Description: Gives the Design options and updates the global variable.
 * *************************/
void designOption(void)
{
        std::cout << "There are four interior options and are as follows..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 1: Hardwood floors for the den, kitchen, and family room. Cost: $10,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 2: All of Option 1 as well as solid brass lighting fixtures in and out. Cost: $20,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 3: All of Option 2 as well as plush carpeting, ceramic tile, and real wood paneling. Cost: $25,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option 4: All of Option 3 as well as gold kitchen and bath fixtures, Jacuzzi and Sauna. Cost: $30,000" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please input 0 for no extra interior features, 1 for Option 1, 2 for Option 2, 3 for Option 3, or 4 for Option 4." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> interiorChoice;

        if(interiorChoice == 0)
        {
                std::cout << "You have chosen to not have any extra interior features." << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 1)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 1. This adds $10,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 10000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 2)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 2. This adds $20,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 20000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 3)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 3. This adds $25,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                optionalFeaturesCost += 25000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else if(interiorChoice == 4)
        {
                std::cout << "You have selected Option 4. This adds $30,000 to your Optional Features Cost." << std::endl;
                option  alFeaturesCost += 30000;
                std::cout << "Your Optional Features Cost is $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << optionalFeaturesCost << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "That is not a valid input." << std::endl;
                                                                                                                                                                                               201,1         63%
```

Comment: this is not really C++ ... and it's way too long for us to wade through ... make a *small* example and post that.

Comment: *What* functions it is complaining about? Please cut the example down to a minimal file showing the problem; trawling through a hundred or so lines looking for a missing declaration or any other mistake is **not** fun enough for me to do it just to answer a stranger's question. Sorry.

Comment: why do you have compiler error messages in your code?

Comment: I will make a small example in a sec. And the program I have to use for school is really crappy and it just didnt paste properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always focus on the very first error you get because it can be the cause of the others. In this case you are missing a semi colon after

```
void bedroomOption(void)
```

which is confusing the compiler causing a lot of fake errors.